# Visual Studio's - How to list contents of array in watch view

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I know in the Visual Studio's watch view, there is a way to list multiple elements from an array. I though it was by adding `,5` to the end of the expression (to view for example the first five elements).

Right now in my watch expression I am adding:

```
NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()[0].GetIPProperties().UnicodeAddresses[0]
```

To view the first address of the network adapter. I was sure I could do:

```
NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()[0].GetIPProperties().UnicodeAddresses,5
```

To allow me to expand the first five entries, but I cannot get it to work. Any suggestions on what the actual syntax is?

(I'm not positive if stackoverflow is the best location for this question, but it seemed fairly programming related).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called **Format Specifiers** and I thing depends on what language you are using...

For example: List of [Format Specifiers in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) versus [Format Specifiers in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby.aspx).

I'm not aware of an option to AutoExpand the first n results through the watch window

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me to what I was remembering. Specifically in the `Format Specifiers in C++` the `Size specifier for Pointers as Arrays` is what I was thinking of. Unfortunately I'm using C# at the moment though.